# Filtering between two dates but with reverse logic

Tags: python, django, date, search, filter

I am making a search that should be able to filter if a "musician" is free between two dates(start_date, end_date). A musician has a calendar which contains the dates of his shows.
So when a user enters the two desired dates in which he wants to book the musician I am supposed to see if the musician does not have a show on at least one of the dates in the range between the two. I was using djagno filter and using .filter() and .exclude() i was able to filter but it excluded musicians that had just one show in the range so obviously it's wrong. I had this piece of code:

```
    def _filter_start_date_end_date(self, queryset):
         queryset = queryset.exclude(shows__performance_date__range=[self.filter_parameters['start_date'],
                                                                self.filter_parameters['end_date']])
         return queryset
```

The queryset contains all the musicians in the database.
Show model:

```
class Show(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    musician = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='shows')

    additional_musicians = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    genres = models.ManyToManyField('Genres', blank=True)
    performance_date = models.DateField()
    performance_start = models.TimeField()
    performance_end = models.TimeField()
```

I hope I asked the question correctly if more information is needed i will provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import datetime


def daterange(d1, d2):
    return (d1 + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range((d2 - d1).days + 1))

    
start_date = self.filter_parameters['start_date']
end_date = self.filter_parameters['end_date']

free_slots = []
for each_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    shows = queryset.filter(
        shows__performance_date=each_date)

    if not shows:
        free_slots.append(each_date)
        
return free_slots  # List of available dates
```